# Como sumar un campo en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Necesito hacer una suma con todos los datos que coincidan con la misma fecha(día). [image: Necesito hacer la suma de los subtotales por día]

he intentado con esto y no funciona

```
SELECT create_at, SUM(subtotal_pres) 
FROM prestaciones 
GROUP BY create_at
```

[image: imagen de la consulta]

Comment: CUando haces group by, estás agrupando las filas con el mismo valor en esa columna. No se ve en nunguna parte que estés agrupando las tres filas en rojo por un campo donde tengan el mismo valor. Parte de la fecha es igual, pero el campo es timestamp, así que agrupa por el campo completo. Prueba extrayendo la fecha sin la hora...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT create_at, SUM(subtotal_pres) 
FROM prestaciones 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(create_at, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Como tu campo es de tipo **timestamp** el cual representa la fecha y también la hora, debes asegurarte de obtener solamente la parte que corresponde a la fecha, para eso usas la **función TO_CHAR**:

```
TO_CHAR(create_at, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

La cual en este caso recibe dos parámetros, el **timestamp** y el formato al que será convertido, **'DD/MM/YYYY'**, devolviendo finalmente una cadena de caracteres solamente con la parte de la fecha.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió mucho .

Comment: @karlo_ si la respuesta te fue util marcala como aceptada, gracias